# ASP.NET MVC JavaScript not working on all table lines

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following asp code

```
<div class="widget-content">
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
           <tr>
              <th id="table_id">
                         Context ID
               </th>
               <th id="">
                         Context Name
               </th>
               <th id="">
                          Context Country
               </th>
               <th id="">
                          Context State
                                </th>
               <th id="">
                           Context City</th>
               <th class="td-actions" id="table_action">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
     <tr>
        <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id);
        </td>


         <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContextName);
        </td>


        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContextCountry.CountryName);
       </td>


       <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContextState.StateName);
                                    </td>

       <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContextCity.CityName);
                                    </td>



       <td class="td-actions">
      <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="#viewModal" id="btnView" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.Id">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> View
                                        </a>

                                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="#editModal" id="btnEdit" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.Id">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="#assignModal" id="btnAssign" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.Id">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Assign
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="@Url.Action("deleteContext","SuperUser", new { id=item.Id})" id="btnDelete" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.Id">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete
                                        </a>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>


                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div> <!-- /widget-content -->
```

And the following java script for View button, which was added for each table line as can be noticed above.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnView').click(function (eve) {
        $('#modal-content').load("/SuperUser/ViewContext/" + $(this).data("id"));
    })
</script>
```

The problem is that, the function is called only for the first table line.

For example.

Line 1 - it will do what needed on View button click

Line 2 - it will not fire the event, or, if the line 1 button was clicked before, it will display the data from line 1 which is not what i expected for this code.

Do you have any idea what can cause this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html. Use class names instead.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I don't get it, can you show an example on this code please? Thanks.

Comment: Replace `id="btnView"` with `class="btnView"` and use `$('.btnView').click(function (...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this:

avoid using duplicate ids, work always with classes if you have a for loop

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id);
                                    </td>


                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContextName);
                                    </td>


                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContextCountry.CountryName);
                                    </td>


                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContextState.StateName);
                                    </td>


                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContextCity.CityName);
                                    </td>



                                    <td class="td-actions">
                                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs btnView" href="#viewModal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.Id">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> View
                                        </a>

                                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs btnEdit" href="#editModal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.Id">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs btnAssign" href="#assignModal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.Id">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Assign
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="@Url.Action("deleteContext","SuperUser", new { id=item.Id})" id="btnDelete" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.Id">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete
                                        </a>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>


                            }
```

for your script, then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.btnView').click(function (eve) {
        $('#modal-content').load("/SuperUser/ViewContext/" + $(this).data("id"));
    })
</script>
```